# Why I can git clone remote repository in terminal but can not in WebStorm?

Tags: git, webstorm

**My current situation:**

I have installed Git in remote server by command `yum install git`.

I have established connection by SSH and I can connect remote server by SSH
command in my local Macbook client.

**My confusion is:**

I can also git clone remote repository by SSH in local terminal. But I can not establish git connection by SSH protocol in WebStorm. The screenshot:

[image]

**By the way, I have change the WebStorm config as:**

[image]

It can not solve my problem still.

Comment: Do you have git bash?

Comment: @NicolásAlarcónR. GitBash is a package for Windows that contains Git and Bash on top of MinGW. macOS does not need GitBash; it contains out of the box everything included in GitBash and even more.

Comment: How do you clone the Git repo using the command line? Does it ask for a password?

Comment: @axiac  Like "git clone ssh://git@118.200.145.15/my_git_repository/demo.git ". It works. I t does not need password because I set it up to login without password.---

Comment: @ axiac  I  am sorry, it need password, maybe my past set did not work well. But whether it asks a password or not is relevant to this problem？

Comment: You need a password at the first start